# Find the derivative of $f(x)=\text{sin}(x^2)\text{ln}(x)$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

I have the following task:

> Find the derivative and state your answer in the simplest form: $$f(x) =\text{sin}(x^2)\text{ln}(x)$$

Here's my attempt:

\begin{align}
f'(x)&=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sin \left(x^2\right)\right)\ln \left(x\right)+\frac{d}{dx}\left(\ln \left(x\right)\right)\sin \left(x^2\right) \\
&= \cos \left(x^2\right)\cdot \:2x\ln \left(x\right)+\frac{1}{x}\sin \left(x^2\right) \\
&= 2x\cos \left(x^2\right)\ln \left(x\right)+\frac{\sin \left(x^2\right)}{x}
\end{align}

I'm pretty sure that the answer is correct but I'm not sure if this is the simplest form. From a glance it does look like it can't be simplified anymore but obviously I could be wrong.

Comment: Right, your result is right, you might do the sum of fraction, to get the simplify form, but I think that you can´t get a pretty result from here

Comment: You *could* write $$x\cos(x^2)\ln(x^2)+\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x}$$ if you really wanted to, or even $$\cos(x^2)\ln(x^{2x})+\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x}$$ if you just wanted an excuse to change something ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You apply the product and chain rules correctly. There is not much to simplify further.

Usually, you can do simplification for [algebraic expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_expression), but not much with [transcendental functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_function).